# You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

code-

```py
    auth_handler = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key=api_key , consumer_secret=api_key_secret)
    auth_handler.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth_handler)
    search_term = 'stocks'
    tweet_amount = 200
    tweets= tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,q=search_term,lang='en').items(tweet_amount)
    
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
```

Comment: use `api.search_recent_tweets` for v2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.